# modern.ie vms json data extract from website

Tags: c++, json, regex, qt

Have question about regexp like i believe, but maybe there better solutions to do it.

I like to extract JSON data from website:
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/

As i see in html code there is a starting point for regexp:

```
<script>var edgePortal = window.edgePortal || {}; edgePortal.vms = {"id":"20151028", ....
```

And is finish with `<script>`

I was try to search over github that maybe some one have some regexp values to extract this JSON,but didn't find anything.

I know that this data is not change every day and can do this extraction manually + some code cleanup (add spaces/tabs etc), but i like to do this using C++/Qt

In Qt there already functions to 'download' html and some basic regexp to extract this data. What i don't know is what filter i can use to get them.

Is filter from: `"softwareList": [` (and a lot of lines ...) to `],"version":` will work, and how to write one?

UPDATE:
I was try to extract from:

```
    {
   "softwareList": [
      {
         "softwareName": "VirtualBox",
         "osList": [
            "Windows",
            "Mac",
            "Linux"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "version": "20151028",
   "active": true,
   "__id": "cbd5c5cd-4e47-40c4-9897-efa391d55d9d",
   "__colId": "vms",
   "_rid": "5AVxAKn1WwDzAAAAAAAAAA==",
   "_ts": 1450222713,
   "_self": "dbs/5AVxAA==/colls/5AVxAKn1WwA=/docs/5AVxAKn1WwDzAAAAAAAAAA==/",
   "_etag": "\"00001a01-0000-0000-0000-5670a4790000\"",
   "_attachments": "attachments/"
}
```

as `(?=softwareList)(.*?)(?=version)` but is not look very well:
https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/285

Comment: the site you posted link to explains how regular expressions work, can't you find the solution based on this?

Comment: it would be nice if you posted the match you want to get from applying the regular expression to your sample text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is filter from: `"softwareList": [` (and a lot of lines ...) to
>   `],"version":` will work, and how to write one?

The regular expresion based on this explanation is as follows:

```
"softwareList": [.*],"version":
```

But it will not apply to the example you added in the update. Depending on what limitations you need the next one will do the job:

```
"softwareList":\s*\[.*\],\s*"version":
```

Here's the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/286).

Comment: Is any way to remove 'version' from it? As i like to have valid JSON, i must remove `,"version"` at end.

Mark answered as is close to what i like to do.

Comment: Unable to edit comment but found what i like to catch!

[link](https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/287)